# Problem installing RStudio onto a GCP cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rstudio, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/running-rstudio-server-on-a-cloud-dataproc-cluster) but keep getting an error when I try to install RStudio on the main cluster. (see section *Installing RStudio Server...*, item 3).

When I run the line

`$ sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.2.1335-amd64.deb`

The installation starts but then fails with

```
Jun 03 03:10:16 cluster-c141-m systemd[1]: Starting RStudio Server...
Jun 03 03:10:16 cluster-c141-m rserver[20313]: /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver: error while loading shar…ectory
Jun 03 03:10:16 cluster-c141-m systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Jun 03 03:10:16 cluster-c141-m systemd[1]: Failed to start RStudio Server.
Jun 03 03:10:16 cluster-c141-m systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 03 03:10:16 cluster-c141-m systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are installing the `rstudio-server` for Debian 8. Install the Debian 9 version.

Comment: thanks, I tried running 
``$ wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/debian9/x86_64/rstudio-server-1.2.1335-amd64.deb
$ sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.2.1335-amd64.deb``
but get error
``● rstudio-server.service - RStudio Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rstudio-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-06-03 04:21:37 UTC; 25ms ago
  Process: 26824 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver (code=exited, status=127)
Jun 03 04:21:37 cluster-c141-m systemd[1]: Failed to start RStudio Server.``

Comment: @Zeus try to remove the previously installed package and run that again. Or run on a clean  cluster

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial could use an update.

There is an initialization action to take care of installation of rstudio (in case you want to create another cluster later): https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/rstudio